# iOS - app specific address book

Tags: ios6

I want to use the look/functionality of the Contacts app to display a list of company employees in my app.  These employees should not be put into the address book of the phone user but be a standalone app specific list.

It seemed like ABPeoplePickerNavigationController is the way to go and that I can set the .addressBook property to an address book I create with ABAddressBookCreate() however when I run this on my phone it loads up all my contacts rather than just the one I have created as a test in my app.  Employees I create are also saved to the central address book of the phone.

Is there a way to create a standalone address book not integrated with the central address book so I can use the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController?  Facebook appear to have done something similar in their app when you look at your friends list.

I am hoping I don't have to build this from the ground up.  There are a couple of similar questions around but nothing definitive.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
CFErrorRef error = NULL;

addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();



ABRecordRef aRecord = ABPersonCreate();
CFErrorRef anError = NULL;
bool didSet;

didSet = ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, CFSTR("Andy"), &anError);
if (!didSet) {/* Handle error here. */}

didSet = ABRecordSetValue(aRecord, kABPersonLastNameProperty, CFSTR("Aardvark"), &anError);
if (!didSet) {/* Handle error here. */}

CFStringRef firstName, lastName;
firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(aRecord, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
lastName  = ABRecordCopyValue(aRecord, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

/* ... Do something with firstName and lastName. ... */
ABAddressBookAddRecord(addressBook, aRecord, &error);

CFRelease(aRecord);
CFRelease(firstName);
CFRelease(lastName);


ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);


ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker =
[[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
picker.addressBook = addressBook;
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
CFRelease(addressBook);
```